# How to check clicks of the user in order to toggle popup? [VueJS]

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, popup, listener

I have a list as component and it contains hidden popup like facebook. For example you click any item on list, and it shows popup about the item
[here is my interface that I mentioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWL44.png)

**here is template**

```
<template id="adboard-group-sidebar-member-template">
<li class="card-item" data-member-id="{{ member.id }}" @click="toggleMemberCard">
item content
</li>
</template>
```

**here is vuejs**

```
toggleMemberCard(event) {
        this.popupDisplayed = !this.popupDisplayed;
    },
```

It runs properly with v-if / v-show attributes. But works only on item list. If the user wants to click any location on the interface. I'm checking like following lines:

```
popupListener(event) {
        let element = $(event.target),
            allCard = $(document).find('.popup'),
            pointer_popup = element[0].closest('.popup'),
            pointer_card = element[0].closest('.card-item');

        if ((!pointer_popup && !pointer_card) || (pointer_popup && pointer_card)) {
            allCard.hide();
        }
    }
```

Also this listens in ready method of VueJS. This is not good solution. I wonder and look for better solution with VueJS.

Comment: What does `popuplistener` do? Like where exactly do you want users to click to open the popup?

Comment: Remove the `[0]` in `element[0].closest`. `.closest()` is a jQuery method. It has to be used on a jQuery element. Using `[0]` gets the DOM element.... So the method won't work.

Comment: This code works correctly, but I don't want to use jquery as much as possible @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: I want to close the popup when the user clicked anywhere out of the popup and list. @kevlai22

Comment: *«I don't want to use jquery as much as possible»* -- `element` is defined as a jQuery element two lines above.

Comment: Yes it was defined. I want to get rid of this usage. @LouysPatriceBessette

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is adding a custom directive to handle the clicks outside that element (i.e., the popup).

```
Vue.directive('click-outside', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    el.event = function (event) {
      // here I check that click was outside the el and his childrens
      if (!(el == event.target || el.contains(event.target))) {
        // and if it did, call method provided in attribute value
        vnode.context[binding.expression](event);
      }
    };
    document.body.addEventListener('click', el.event)
  },
  unbind: function (el) {
    document.body.removeEventListener('click', el.event)
  },
});
```

Here's a working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/70vm3jrd/1/)

You can find more info about custom directives and what **el, binding, vnode** means in https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Directive-Hook-Arguments

Answer (score 0):

Try this... Sadly, it uses the powerfull jQuery library.

```
let element = $(event.target),
allCard = $(document).find('.popup'),
pointer_popup = element.closest('.popup').length,
pointer_card = element.closest('.card-item').length;

if (pointer_popup == 0 && pointer_card == 0) {
  allCard.hide();
}
```

You want to check if there is a "closest" element... Check the `length` of the resulting jQuery lookup.